# Deploy Spark on multiple subnets on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I want to deploy spark on EC2 using `spark-ec2` tool. The target environment is a private VPC spanned over 3 availability zone. I see from the docs that I can distribute my instances over AZs by adding `--zone=all` but it's not the same for `--subnet-id` param because it only accepts one input.

How can I introduce more that one subnets to the tool? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Why won't you use EMR directly?

Comment: @eliasah Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I need more flexibility (such as running my cluster in a private VPC). Anyhow if the scripts are not straightforward enough, I will go with EMR.

Comment: You can run your cluster in a private VPC with EMR the last time I checked.

Comment: AWS Docs: "Because access to and from the AWS cloud is a requirement of the cluster, you must connect an Internet gateway to the subnet hosting the cluster". Maybe I am missing something but my reading is that the EMR instances should have public IPs so that they can be managed by AWS.

Comment: @asaad You were ahead of the times. Two months after you posted this they started allowed EMR in private subnets.